# How I can download video in my application like we download or install apk file on google play?

Tags: android, download, android-videoview

I want to download video from URL in background like we install apk file in background from Google play. I want to show downloading indicator on notification bar same like it showing while we download or install apk file. if any suggestion or idea then suggest me how I can achieve this task in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prefer android [DownLoadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html).
 somehow want to do like this in your activity

```
String mUrl="your video url";

DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
Request request = new Request(Uri.parse(mUrl));
            request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getApplicationContext(), Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, your_fileName);
            request.setNotificationVisibility(Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE);
            request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
            request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
            manager.enqueue(request);
```

`setNotificationVisibility()` -> show download notification in notification bar(window) with download progress also.

**below are three methods where you can choose destination for your downloaded file path.**

1. `setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(Context context, String dirType, String subPath)`
Set the local destination for the downloaded file to a path within the application's external files directory (as returned by getExternalFilesDir(String).

2. `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(String dirType, String subPath)`
Set the local destination for the downloaded file to a path within the public external storage directory (as returned by getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String)).

`3. setDestinationUri(Uri uri)`
Set the local destination for the downloaded file.

Comment: where will save video? how can add folder name?

Answer (score 0):

Use Download Manager,

```
private void for_call_download() {
        File folder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DOWNLOAD_FOLDER_NAME);
        if (!folder.exists() || !folder.isDirectory()) {
            folder.mkdirs();
        }
        try {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(APK_URL));
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(DOWNLOAD_FOLDER_NAME, DOWNLOAD_FILE_NAME);
            request.setTitle(SessionName);
            request.setDescription("" + SessionDesc);
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false);
            request.setMimeType("application/cn.trinea.download.file");
            downloadId = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
        } catch (IllegalStateException i) {
            showAlert(context, "Sorry Some Problem");
            i.printStackTrace();
        }
        updateView();
        status_download = true;
    }
```